# Racket Contract Failing Where It Shouldn't

Tags: lisp, racket, contract

I have a struct that represents a move

```
(struct move (tile x y rotations) #:prefab)
```

Pass is also allowed, so I have a bool that test for an action:

```
(define (action? v)
  (if (or (pass? v)
          (move? v))
      #t
      ;; else
      #f
  )
)
```

I can declare a move like

```
(define test (move (tile 'blue (list (posn 0 0 ) (posn 1 0) (posn 2 0) (posn 3 0) (posn 3 1))) 2 4 0))
```

And when I test for action? it passes:

> (action? test)
>       #t

However, when I use this file on a different module, the move structure is not accepted as a valid move:

> state-transition: contract violation
>    expected: (and/c action? ???)
>    given: '#s(move #s(tile blue (#s(posn 0 0) #s(posn 1 0) #s(posn 2 0) #s(posn 3 0) #s(posn 3 1))) 2 4 0)
>    which isn't: ???

Here is the state-transition contract provided by the teacher:

```
[state-transition (->i ([s state?]
          [a (s) (and/c action?
                (cut state-action-legal? <> s))])
         [result state?])]
```

So I have basically the same object in two places. In one of them it passes the test, and in the other one it fails and a contract is broken. Why is this happening?

**Edit**

Here is the definition of state-action-legal?

```
(define (state-action-legal? state action)
  (not (state-action-violation state action))
)
```

And **state-action-violation** returns string indicating the reason the action is not legal or #F if the action is legal. I know they are both working properly because we tested them manually and the teacher provided unit tests to ensure proper implementation and these functions pass all of them.

**End edit**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It shouldn't affect this output, but is there a reason you're doing `(if something #t #f)` as opposed to `something`?  I.e., why not `(define (action? v) (or (pass? v) (move? v)))`?

Comment: Force of habit. Most contracts specify the return value must be #t or #f and and? returns the last true value, often a list, that would break the contract. By the time we wrote this function, we had broken a lot of contracts for that reason and just wrote the functions that way from the beginning.

Comment: The error says that the failing contract may not necessarily be on `action?`, but on the `???` part, which seems to be `state-action-legal?`. Can you give the definition of this function? As I understand it, it seems that you are not allowed to do the specified action `a` in the state `s`, even if it can be an `action?`.

Comment: @Metaxal I included the definition of the function. The action is being selected from a list of legal actions so I know that the move is legal. I tested it by creating a move with the same attributes and testing it manually. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to find out what is the state `s` for which `(state-transition s test)` fails. Then try`(state-action-violation s test)`. I think it will not return `#f`. Btw, passing all given unit tests never ensures that the function works properly. It can only give you more confidence.